# simplest fail over support for standard rdbms?

Tags: database, rdbms, failover

Currently I am working on failover support of an existing application.

The application uses postgres to store data but does not use any special feature (view/trigger etc). The database is more of a configuration storage rather than real data storage. When the application starts, it loads the data in memory and seldom goes back to database only when the configurations are changed. Trying to configure postgres failover solution for this simple task feels like overkill.

Is there any lightweight database which has built in failover support and simple to configure and use in production? Most of my data model is single table and there are like 5 transactions per minute or so.

Answer (score 1):

[BerkeleyDB](http://www.oracle.com/technology/products/berkeley-db/index.html) is a very simple key/value store, probably it is perfectly adequate for your application, and it has support for [hot failover](http://www.oracle.com/technology/documentation/berkeley-db/db/programmer_reference/transapp_hotfail.html).